# Smooth Scrolling is all glitchy! (this is a code block on squarespace)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I am clicking the 'Explore' button, it seems to glitch, like it's trying to scroll down twice or something. The website is a squarespace one, I thought perhaps I am misunderstanding the prevent default behaviour part. Any help is appreciated.

The  it is scrolling too is coded:

To see what's going wrong, follow link: wolfcreatives.com

Thanks!!

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>

<body>

<a id="explore" href="#section2"><span>EXPLORE </span></a>

<div class="main">
  <section></section>
</div>

<style>
#explore {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: solid 2px white;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: raleway;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 110px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#explore span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#explore span:after {
  content: '⇩';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  transition: 0s;
}

#explore:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#explore:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#explore:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, or see an issue in the site...can you specify what browser your issue is in?

Comment: I second @RichardGuy, it works great for me on Google Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I third that, also seems fine in Firefox.

Comment: Odd! If you are following the link recently, I removed the JavaScript and left the CSS to do a basic scroll with no timings. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the event from propagation up the DOM tree - [StopImmediatePropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/#event-stopImmediatePropagation)

Also, if you just want to do scrolling on explore button, you can use more specific selector other than tag name. For example, you can use id `#explore` as selector

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("#explore").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to stop the propagation? Usually this is only required if you are firing the same event you are catching from within the closuere.

Comment: Yes, there must be some other code firing event handler which I can not find. Thanks for the tip related to stop propagation guys. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what other code conflicted with this but this prevent propagation worked perfectly! :) Thank you!